# loading spinner does show even if its true condition in angular

Tags: angular

I have a loader which is simple :

```
 <div *ngIf="loadingSpinner" class="k-i-loading"></div>
```

on top of my .ts class i set it false:

```
public loadingSpinner:boolean=false;
```

i want it to be set to true when the following function is hit:

```
       <div class="card" (click)="SendToBank()">
          <div *ngIf="loadingSpinner" class="k-i-loading"></div>
         </div>
```

in my function In the beginning i set it to true to start showing until the data is fetched from the back end and once its done set it to false again,where im doing wrong that i cant see the spinner after function is hit?

```
        SendToBank(){

    this.loadingSpinner=true;
    this.http.get(`http://localhost:44301/consentinitiation/${this.qid}`)
      .pipe(retryWhen(_ => {
        this.showIt=true
        return interval(1000)
      }))
      .subscribe(result => {result
      console.log(result);
      this.qrcodelink=result["qrCodeLink"];
      this.loadingSpinner=false;
      })

    }
```

Comment: are you using onpush strategy?

Comment: what onpush?@AakashGarg

Comment: in your pipe try to put a delay method with time as 10000 then verify.

Comment: @AakashGarg right before my http call i set it to true,right?why does not show  in your idea?

Comment: because subscribe getting called too quickly, i.e. your api call finishing very quickly. thats why you are not able to see it.

Comment: maybe try to remove this.loadingspinner = false.

Comment: @AakashGarg whats the best way to this then?i need to get data from database and start the loader ,once finished just stop it,no idea how

Comment: first try to remove this.loadingspinner = false and then tell if loader is visible

Comment: @AakashGarg i removed it from the bottom line inside my http call,but still is not showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can please verify that this "SendToBack" function is getting called on click?
Also, I don't see any code inside

```
<div *ngIf="loadingSpinner" class="k-i-loading"></div>
```

So it is just an empty div tag maybe that's why you are not seeing anything.

also you can try to use

```
SendToBank(){

this.loadingSpinner=true;
this.http.get(`http://localhost:44301/consentinitiation/${this.qid}`)
  .pipe(retryWhen(_ => {
    this.showIt=true
    return interval(1000)
  }))
  .subscribe(result => {result
  console.log(result);
  this.qrcodelink=result["qrCodeLink"];
  setTimeout(() => {
      this.loadingSpinner=false;
  }, 5000);
  
  })

}
```

if none of these works then kindly provide the the code of that class "k-i-loading". i would like to help.

Comment: thanks for the answer,may i ask whats the reason of that setTimeout?

Comment: i think you are getting the API response in very short time. so like the variable to setting to false within micro seconds. so if you add setTimeout function then the angular will wait for specified amount of time before setting the variable to false. you can see the spinner if there is any :D

Comment: here is the explaination @masali

Comment: its showing!but is it the right way now?i mean with settime?and once the data is retrieved it will be hidden?

Comment: Actually we should not use setTimeout generally for any data manipulation-related logic. I personally do not suggest using the SetTimeout function for other data manipulation. but in this case since you are getting data back very quickly then I think you can remove this function. but if you still wanna display the spinner so that user will know that something has been loaded on the page then you can use this timeout function with very time amount value (800 - 1000) instead 5000. also if you want to use this then I suggest you should not add any other code logic in it. @masali